# SocketRocket/SocketRocket.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, socket.io

I'm using pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift' and pod 'SocketRocket'

its working fine on Simulator and device then connected issue occur then i will try to create Archive file then Showing First error

error: Invalid bitcode signature
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

After BitCode = No Then Showing Below error

SocketRocket/SocketRocket.h' and SocketIO/SocketIO-Swift.h file not found

Help me My Project almost Complete I was stuck in this issue